# Difference of consecutive float numbers in a column

Tags: python

I have a list of floating point numbers in a file in column like this:

123.456

234.567

345.678

How can i generate an output file which is generated by subtracting the value in a line with the value just above it. For the input file above,the output generated should be:

123.456-123.456

234.567-123.456

345.678-234.567

The first value should return zero, but the other values should get subtracted with the value just above it. This is not an homework question. This is a small requirement of my bigger problem and i am stuck at this point. Help much appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you stuck trying to read the files or is it the float math?

Comment: I have no prolem in reading and writing into files. The problem is that i cannot think of any logic how to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
diffs = [0] + [j - data[i] for i,j in enumerate(data[1:])]
```

So, assuming `data.txt` contains:

```
123.456
234.567
345.678
```

then

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    diffs = [0] + [float(j) - float(data[i]) for i,j in enumerate(data[1:])]

print diffs
```

will yield

```
[0, 111.111, 111.11099999999999]
```

This answer assumes you want to keep the computed values for further processing.

If at some point you want to write these out to a file, line by line:

```
with open('result.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for i in diffs:
        outf.write('{0:12.5f}\n'.format(i))
```

and adjust the field widths to suit your needs (right now 12 spaces reserved, 5 after the decimal point), written out to file `result.txt`.

**UPDATE**: Given (from the comments below) that there is possibly too much data to hold in memory, this solution should work. Python 2.6 doesn't allow opening both files in the same `with`, hence the separate statements.

```
with open('result2.txt', 'w') as outf:
    outf.write('{0:12.5f}\n'.format(0.0))
    prev_item = 0;
    with open('data.txt') as inf:
        for i, item in enumerate(inf):
            item = float(item.strip())
            val = item - prev_item
            if i > 0:
                outf.write('{0:12.5f}\n'.format(val))
            prev_item = item
```

Has a bit of a feel of a hack. Doesn't create a huge list in memory though.

Comment: This program is generating comma seperated values. How to generate them line by line(each vaue in each line)

Comment: `data = f.readlines()` in this case `data` contents will be something like `['123.456\n', '234.567\n']`..etc

Comment: and also in the program above, you need to type cast j and data[i] with float()

Comment: how can i write these values into a file line by line?

Comment: @Levon, i am getting the following error: ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @learner are you using Python 2.6 or before? If so put a `0` before the colon, i.e., `outf.write('{0:12.5f}\n'.format(i))` - let me know if that fixes it. (I'm running this here w/o problems)

Comment: yup, its working...but i have a small concern. There is a limit to the size a variable can hold in python. In my program, i have 20,00,000 values. I think diffs cannot hold that many values. We are just writing comma seperated values stored in variable diffs line by line, thats all. Any idea on this?

Comment: @learner I updated my answer with a solution that does not create a list in memory (in your case very large give your data). It seems to work, but I would recommend you test it with a few small data files to convince yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of values:

```
[values[i] - values[i-1] if i > 0 else 0.0 for i in range(len(values))]
```

Comment: @hochl, a list comprehension can be trivially converted to a generator and it's easier to see immediate results.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of list comprehensions or generator expressions, why not write your own generator that can have arbitrarily complex logic and easily operate on enormous data sets?

```
from itertools import imap

def differences(values):
    yield 0  # The initial 0 you wanted
    iterator = imap(float, values)
    last = iterator.next()
    for value in iterator:
        yield value - last
        last = value

with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for value in differences(data):
        f.write('%s\n' % value)
```

If `data` holds just a few values, the benefit wouldn't necessarily be so clear (although the explicitness of the code itself might be nice next year when you have to come back and maintain it). But suppose `data` was a stream of values from a huge (or infinite!) source and you wanted to process the first thousand values from it:

```
diffs = differences(enormousdataset)
for count in xrange(1000):
    print diffs.next()
```

Finally, this plays well with data sources that aren't indexable. Solutions that track index numbers to look up values don't play well with the output of generators.